# Could the Universe have monster symmetry?

Tags: string-theory, group-theory

The Monster Group is the largest "sporadic simple group" with order:
 808,017,424,794,512,875,886,459,904,961,710,757,005,754,368,000,000,000

I read that if you compactify 26D bosonic string theory on the 24D torus given by the Leech Lattice, then you end up with a vertex algebra with Monster Group symmetry.

I also read that heterotic string theoy is a combination of 26D string theory and 10D superstring theory for left/right modes.

But then I also read we might be living on a 3-brane in a higher dimensional bulk space.

So if this bulk space was on a 24D torus (a very large one, so large we couldn't tell),

then would this mean that the Universe did have Monster symmetry?

I think the Monster group is a really interesting object and it would be cool if this was a symmetry of the Universe. But I don't really know enough about these things.

Comment: so are you soliciting opinions?

Comment: I am asking a question. It's either yes or no.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but maybe check [Understanding the Monster CFT](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/39539) and Witten's paper [Three-D Gravity Reconsidered](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3359), which says: "We consider the problem of identifying the CFTs that may be dual to pure gravity in three dimensions with negative cosmological constant. ... At the most negative possible value of the cosmological constant, the dual CFT is very likely the monster theory of [FLM]. ... Arguably, the FLM model is the most natural known structure with [Monster] symmetry." This paper cites more ref's.

Comment: @Chiral Interesting. Yes, because compactifying 26D bosonic string theory on 24D lattice leaves a 2D CFT. And perhaps Witten is saying that with AdS CFT correspondence then this would give gravity in 3 dimensions. (Even though, the Universe has 4 dimensions!) I go by the opinion if the Universe doesn't have Monster symmetry, I don't want to live in it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheap point is that there is no symmetry we can ever rule out. Just let all of the fields we've observed be singlets under that symmetry and posit that new fields transforming faithfully under it are extremely massive. But you are asking whether the importance of the monster group in string theory makes it more likely to be realized in nature and I don't think that's the case.

The applications of the monster CFT are pretty far from phenomenology. It was first used to prove conjectures from pure mathematics and it continues to be useful as a sort of building block for rational CFTs. This is because it provides one of the rare situations where you can get away with only left movers or only right movers. More often, both have to be combined in a special way (which is the GSO projection) in order to have modular invariance.

This last statement is reminiscent of heterotic string theory where the fermions are all left moving but the dimensions involved are different. To have a 10d target space on both sides, the right moving bosons must be compactified on a 16d manifold. And for anomaly reasons, this should be a torus given by the root lattice of either $SO(32)$ or $E_8 \times E_8$ which both have rank 16. A relation to our universe can then be attempted by introducing a 3-brane or a further compactification on a 6d manifold.